# Django Group_by Date with Sum Data

Tags: django, date, group-by, sum, sql-order-by

I need to combing many acct_id's records into a single summary grouped by the "month" field.  All the other data like "value" and "cash_in" need to be Sum()

```
class Cashflow ( models.Model ):
   acct_id = models.ForeignKey ( Acct )
   month = models.DateField ( auto_now = False, auto_now_add = False, null = False, blank = True )
   value = models.IntegerField ( blank = True, default = 0 )
   cash_in = models.IntegerField ( blank = True, default = 0 )
   cash_out = models.IntegerField ( blank = True, default = 0 )
   transfer = models.IntegerField ( default = 0 )
```

I am having a difficult time getting all the data to group.

Also would like the months to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this is the best way to do it, but it seems to be working.

any advice on improving would be appreciated.  cheers.

```
qs = Cashflow.objects.all () 
    .filter ( acct_id = id ) 
    .annotate ( m = TruncDate ( 'month' ) ) 
    .order_by ( 'm' ) 
    .values ( 'm' ) 
    .annotate ( **{ 'value': Sum ( 'value' ) } ) 
    .annotate ( **{ 'cash_in': Sum ( 'cash_in' ) } ) 
    .annotate ( **{ 'cash_out': Sum ( 'cash_out' ) } ) 
    .annotate ( **{ 'transfer': Sum ( 'transfer' ) } )
```